# Bash script to upload first RAR part to ftp, before completion of second part (To Save Time and space)

Tags: bash, rar

i was making a bash script for my server which pack some directories with RAR and upload it to other ftp server, so some folders are big and i have to rar them in parts and have to wait for all parts to be rared before uploading them, which consumes lots of time and space

so i want to do it more fast like, upload every rared part on its completion and delete it afterwards automatically without waiting for another all parts, i know there are possibilities of getting data corrupted or else, but that's what i want to do and i confused about where to start the script.

Server OS: Ubuntu 9.10

thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Start rar in the background
- Check wheter rar is finished on the part by calling `fuser foo.part2.rar`.
- If `fuser` does not return anything, you can transfer it to the remote FTP.

Comment: great idea, then i have to call rar from another bash scripts and i can check parts in main script.